# Can I use table Alias in HAVING clause in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Can I use a table alias from the outer query inside a subquery in MySQL?
I am using mysql-server 5.7.21.

If yes, why the following codes don't work?
If No, what is the syntax reason for it?

Table request_accepted
| a_id | b_id |     date   |
|------|------|------------|
| 1    | 2    | 2018-06-03 |
| 1    | 3    | 2018-06-02 |
| 2    | 3    | 2018-06-01 |
| 3    | 4    | 2018-06-05 |

When I not using the alias 'x' but the whole query in the having clause, it worked.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS 'num' FROM (
SELECT a_id AS id FROM Date
UNION ALL
SELECT b_id AS id FROM Date
) x
GROUP by id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=ALL(SELECT COUNT(*) from x group by id )
```

Runtime Error
Table 'test.x' doesn't exist

Comment: You can use a table alias in a HAVING clause, but not in a subquery like that. If is is a newer version of mysql, you could probably use a CTE like that though.

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.x you can avoid computing the values twice by using CTEs (Common Table Expressions). What's you database version? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Describe what you are trying to achieve - i bet there are many clever solutions to this groupwise-max problem. Are you trying to find the ID with the most requests and/or acceptance? Or the one that sent the most requests? What is the use case?

Comment: I am using mysql-server 5.7.21. Based on your comment, I can use a table alias in HAVING clause, but 1) I can not use a table alias inside a subquery? or) I cannot use a table alias in a subquery inside a HAVING clause? if so, is there any reference about this syntax error?

Comment: @peter1fan2 Please edit your question to include a [mcve], which can be run by others that produces the error. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions and add the information to your question.